# Python IPython Turning variables to strings

Tags: python

I have a function that creates new Jupyter Notebook cells and I'm trying to use a loop to show value counts for each column and the specific difficulty I have is having them return with the column names in quotes. Here's what I have:

```
def create_new_cell(contents):
    shell = get_ipython()
    payload = dict(
        source='set_next_input',
        text=contents,
        replace=False,
    )
    shell.payload_manager.write_payload(payload, single=False)

def show_vc(col):
    col = (f'(col)')
    content = "df[{col_name}].value_counts()"\
        .format(col_name=col)
    create_new_cell(content)
```

^ This returns an actual 'col' instead of what I want, which is the series name.

I've tried replacing

```
col = (f'(col)')
```

with things like

```
col = str(col)
```

or

```
col = "(col)"
```

but nothing has worked for me and I'm admittedly thinking about how to properly word this in a way so it will execute properly when I'm running my next cell, which is

```
for x in df.columns:
    show_vc(x)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot curly brackets.
You need to use them to replace the field with the variable.

`col = f'{col}'`

Test code

```
col = 'column'
col = f'{col}'
print(col)
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate your help. I tried it, but it doesn't result in this properly working. The cell didn't have the strings in them. Here's an example of what I got. df[(Month)].value_counts()

Comment: Could it have to do with my function and the use of ipython?

Comment: replace `content = "df[{col_name}].value_counts()"\
        .format(col_name=col)`   to  this `content = (lambda x : df[x].value_counts())(col)`

Comment: I saw your answer below. because you didn't gave the ideal result, I couldn't answer right. I thought somehow you want to keep braces. with your answer below, try this. `col = f'{col}'`

Answer (score 0):

So I just found the answer. I had to use Pretty Print.

```
def show_vc(col):
    col = pformat(col)
    #col = f'({col})'
    content = "df[{col_name}].value_counts()"\
        .format(col_name=col)
    create_new_cell(content)
```

The output looked like this:

[image: ```]